# Ant Design Tab unwarranted button

Tags: tabs, antd

I have the following antd Tabs. How to get rid of the ... button on the right? (Note that it disappears when the screen width is decreased.)

[image]

The structure is like this:

```
<Tabs type="card">
                        <TabPane tab="A">
                            .....
                        </TabPane>
                        <TabPane tab="B">
                            .....
                        </TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

This is the style:

```
.ant-tabs-tab {
   flex-grow: 1;
   margin-right: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 15px;
   justify-content: center;
   color: #94a3ac;
 }

 .ant-tabs-nav-list {
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: 6px solid #093150;
 }

 .ant-tabs-top > .ant-tabs-nav {
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 .ant-tabs-card > .ant-tabs-nav .ant-tabs-tab {
   border: none;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.68);
 }

 .ant-tabs-tab-active {
   background-color: #093150 !important;
   .ant-tabs-tab-btn {
     color: white !important;
   }
```

Comment: Your picture can not load, Can you re-upload?

Comment: @Mocuishle Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your css :

`ant-tabs-nav-more { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect element like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiNRh.png)

then add code in your css:

```css
.ant-tabs-nav-operations {
  display: none !important;
}
```